# to which member group would belong pending members?

Tags: members, multi-site-manager, registration

**SHORT ANSWER :** YOU CAN'T TELL

---

I have 2 member groups.

When a registration is not complete, (email not confirmed) the registred user is placed in Pending member group.

How can I know which group it would have been assigned to if he had completed the registration process ?

As a side note : I use MSM, is there any way to know at least which site the member tried to register to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use default EE registration, you can setup **Default Member Group Assigned to New Members** in *Members -> Member Preferences*.

Regarding site - is no such function from the box. You can add hidden field on reg page where you will keep site id or site name.

Comment: this does not answer my question, I have two groups (one per site) site_1 defaults to member_group_1 and site_2 defaults to member_group_2. Pending Members group is common to the two sites (that's how things work) hence my question :  How can I know which group a member would have been assigned to if he had completed the registration process ?

Comment: What do u use for registration form? Is it native?

Comment: If you use native form and setup member group in Member Preferences, you could have only one group for all sites. If you have already different groups already, it means that you use some third-party solution for registration. It could be User, Zoo Visitors, etc.. They all kept information about the future group in they tables. So, as I suggest in the first time - the easiest is way creates a custom member field and populate it as hidden field on reg page with information about the site or future group.

Comment: Max, you're wrong. with MSM default member group is set on a per site basis.

Comment: Member groups are installation wide, but you can set group1 as default for site 1 and group2 as default for site2. The info about which group a member is pending for must be stored somewhere, my question is where ? :)

Comment: You right :( my mistake. I missed site_id in configs. ok, I recheck EE native activation process code - is not keep group anywhere. It's used default group for specific site ( Member Self-Activation function - $group_id = ee()->config->item('default_member_group')). For example, Zoo Visitors has table exp_zoo_visitor_activation_membergroup, Solspace User - exp_user_activation_group. So my original answer is still correct.

Comment: Well I understand, that gives me no way to know which site my pending members belong :/ that's definitely #1 on my feature request list